# How to disallow ssh jumps

Tags: debian, ssh, vmware

I'm looking for a method to disallow users to use a particular Debian 10.10 host as an SSH jump host. I want to stop them from connecting with SSH from this host.

- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have `AllowTcpForwarding no`.
- In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I have `FollowAgent no`.

But when I connect, I can connect to another host.

How to deny/lock/block a new SSH connection from the first SSH connection?

```
HOST A --{SSH}--> Other_Host_N --{NO SSH}--X--> hyp_vmware
```

Comment: Did you restart the ssh server on Host B after making changes to `sshd_config`?

Comment: Setting `AllowTcpForwarding` does not prevent someone running `ssh` on Host B

Comment: Yes I restart and reload the conf but I can connect to other hosts after.

Comment: If you want Other_Host to not accept ssh connections from Host_B, wouldn't it be a config in Other_Host's `sshd_config` file?

Comment: I don't search filter by host but don't do a new ssh connection again from first ssh connection.

Comment: An user could just do ssh inside the shell, so a poor man jumping. So just firewall outbound connections (e.g. with a white or black list or networks/hosts). But maybe first you should ask: shy users are doing it? And solve the problem. Possibly you need a jump host on perimeter (easy to protect) and strong firewall on all other incoming connections (from outside).

Comment: Firewall rule to prevent outgoing connections to ssh-ports is the only barely working way.

Comment: Another option would be to remove the `ssh` client from the host that's reachable from Host_A.  However, as has been pointed out, if a user who ssh'es into Host_A has normal access to commands and files, the user can likely copy an `ssh` executable file into their home directory and invoke that.  And probably there are uses of an `ssh` client that you want to retain, so I don't offer this as a **good** option, just saying it's an option.

Comment: @SottoVoce, well, having the SSH client available or not on the intermediate host would only matter if the user wants to terminate their final SSH connection on the intermediate (needing to trust it), instead of just having the final encrypted tunnel take detour through it. There are some rather obvious of doing the latter, e.g. `ssh -W` or `ssh`+`netcat` (with `ProxyCommand`). See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635613/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-proxycommand-w-nc-exec-nc). Heck, even Bash _might_ do, since it has rudimentary support for network sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's all responses, analyses and others.

I start to rename "other_host" schema by "Hyp_vmware" because he is the "other_host".

Today I setted a rule in the ESXi firewall with deny all connection by ssh and allowed the desired IP. Because the ESXi 7.0 dont have "TCP wrappers" (In linux yes).

I get the "ilkkachu" answer reference and adapt in ESXi CLI.

Please note the ESXi command is different of "ilkkachu" answer.
You can filter ip with this command:

```
esxcli network firewall ruleset set --ruleset-id=sshServer --enabled=true
esxcli network firewall ruleset allowedip add -i @IP -r sshServer
esxcli network firewall refresh
```

Cordially

Answer (score 4):

Prevent outgoing SSH connections from the intermediate host to the "forbidden" target host. With iptables on Linux, something like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d forbiddenhost -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

(Or the other way, drop incoming SSH connections from the intermediate host on the target host.)

---

Note that just preventing a new SSH connection from originating on the intermediate might not do, as there are a few common ways of using jump hosts only to pass the encrypted data from the origin to the final destination. That is, instead of putting two pipes back-to-back:

```
origin *---SSH---* intermediate *---SSH---* target
```

one would route one half of a single pipe inside another pipe, bent to pass through the intermediate host:

```
origin           intermediate        target
    *-]=== tunnel ===[-------SSH-------*
```

That tunnel part could be another SSH connection, or e.g. just a plain TCP connection (possibly set up with port forwarding in SSH). Whatever it is, it just passes through the SSH connection originating from "origin". The upside of all this is that the user doesn't need to trust the intermediate host with their unencrypted data. The downside of course being the extra overhead in the SSH over SSH case. (Running SSH over a forwarded TCP connection wouldn't actually be any overhead compared to the usual SSH usage.)

Some simple ways of doing something like that are using SSH's `ProxyCommand` with either `ssh intermediatehost -W targethost:22`, or `ssh intermediatehost nc targethost 22` (or so). See e.g. [What is the difference between ssh proxycommand -W, nc, exec nc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635613/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-proxycommand-w-nc-exec-nc) on SO.

All that's needed for the intermediate to work as a jump host is *some* way of opening a network connection from it to the final target host.  A user with an even a borderline normal shell access could download a static copy of `nc` if it isn't installed, or write a short Perl script, or whatever. Even just using Bash might do, since it has some support for opening network connections with redirections.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is basically impossible for users that get shell access; any such user that can log in via SSH can also execute anything in that shell they're getting, including:

- starting a separate `ssh` process and connecting to another host
- copying over a statically compiled ssh that they then use
- downloading and executing arbitrary software.

So, you've basically given them the privilege to do what is functionally an SSH jump. You might only disable the convenience of the SSH daemon itself offering jumphost capabilities. This does not seem to be enough for you.

Essentially, you need to make a choice: do you really want users to have access, including to network, from the machine that they're connecting to?

If the answer is "no", then the solution is straightforward: Don't give them access to a machine with that kind of network access. This is a pretty common setting e.g. in universities with some compute server running some software that students and researchers can access via SSH, but which should not give them access to the internal networks. Having your SSH daemon run on its own IPv6 address in its own Linux network namespace, with no connectivity to the internet (or whatever network you don't want users to be able to jump to) solves that problem, basically for free.

Comment: No, not _any_ user that can log in via SSH. It's possible to change the user's shell to something that only allows a restricted set of actions. But they're not even remotely regular users then. (Like you said, trying to prevent them from running a particular command will just lead to workarounds, but you could just whitelist a very restricted set of commands.)

Comment: @ilkkachu true. What I wrote here only applies to a shell-enabled user. Tried to specify in 1st sentence. Thanks!